# Need a Batch file copy all txt files to a sub folder, but rename if it already exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

Ok,

I have multiple text files that will be coming into a folder that I am processing into a single output file. The batch will run every few hours.

```
    for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> ESOComplete\ESOInput.txt
```

This will copy all text from text files to one single text file in another subfolder.

From there I need one to move all files (Example 510002.txt) to a subfolder called ESOMoved. Leaving the root folder empty so next time the batch runs it doesn't add the same data to the ESOInput.txt

Now, I need the batch file that moves the orignal data from the root to not overwrite, so if files already exists I want it to rename it (From 510002.txt to 510002**2**.txt)

In the end it should be 
1. Move all text from all .txt documents to one output file. (Which is already done)
2. Move all .txt documents to subfolder called ESOMoved, unless that specific document already exists, in which case rename, and then move.

Comment: Both move and rename can be realized with the "move" command.

Comment: Is that really how you want to rename them? add a 2 right before the extension? Also: Is there ever a chance that both 510002.txt & 510002**2**.txt will both exist?

Comment: @ddbug But I need the IF Exiists wrote...

Comment: @3D1T0R Yes that is it. All the files will be 6 digit numbers so the seventh digit will just be for version of repeat file names.

Comment: It should be 2 if the original string exists, 3 if 2 exists, 4 if 3 exists and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
If the file with the appended `2` already exists the number is increased until it is free.

```
@Echo off
:: Start in base folder
PushD "Q:\Test\2017\07\22"

for %%f in (??????.txt) do (
    type "%%f" >> "ESOComplete\ESOInput.txt"
    If Not Exist "ESOMoved\%%f" (
        Move "%%f" "ESOMoved\"
    ) Else (
        Set Num=2
        Call :Move "%%f" 
    )
)
PopD
Goto :Eof
:Move
Set "NewName=ESOMoved\%~n1%Num%%~x1"
If Not Exist "%NewName%" (
Echo Move %1 "%NewName%"
     Move %1 "%NewName%" >Nul 2>&1
     Exit /B 0
)
Set /A Num+=1
Goto :Move
```

Comment: This is looking great, Only issue is
1. When it moves it it takes off the file extension so I changed
    Move "%%f" "ESOMoved\%%~nf2%%xf"
to
    Move "%%f" "ESOMoved\%%~nf2%%xf.txt"

2. I need all text files which some of them seem to be more that 6 charactors so I changed
    for %%f in (??????.txt) do (
to
    for %%f in (*.txt) do (

3. What I really need isn't "2" added but I need the next available number added to rename.

IF 51001 exists
change to 510012
If that exists change next one to 510013
Then to 510014 etc.

This one is overwriting the second one, with 3rd one.

Comment: @cameroncarlson Edited batch to auto increase the appended number.

Comment: @cameroncarlson: That "next available number" is what I was asking about before.

Comment: @LotPings: This looks very much like what I was in the middle of writing, but I'm pretty sure he wants `*.txt` not `??????.txt`

Comment: @cameroncarlson: The reason the first version accidentally removed the file extension was because the `%%xf` should have been `%%~xf`

Comment: Thank you!! This is EXACTLY what I needed!

Comment: @Echo off
    :: Start in base folder
    PushD "D:\Archive\Pressurecontrol_Data\ESO"
    
     for %%f in (*.txt) do (
        type "%%f" >> "ESOComplete\ESOInput.txt"
        If Not Exist "ESOMoved\%%f" (
             Move "%%f" "ESOMoved\"     
        ) Else (
            Set Num=2
             Call :Move "%%f" 
        )
     ) 
     PopD
     Goto :Eof
     :Move
     Set "NewName=ESOMoved\%~n1_%Num%%~x1"
     If Not Exist "%NewName%" (
     Echo Move %1 "%NewName%"
     Move %1 "%NewName%" >Nul 2>&1
     Exit /B 0
)
    Set /A Num+=1
    Goto :Move

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this is devising a renaming scheme. The code below appends "-N" to the file basename to create a unique file it will keep incrementing N until if finds a filename that does not exist.

Save this file as `esomover.ps1`.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:/src/t/ESO/' -File -Filter 'file*.txt'

$sum_file = 'C:/src/t/ESO/ESOComplete/ESOInput.txt'
$arch_dir = 'C:/src/t/ESO/ESOArchive'

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $sum_file)) { New-Item -Path $sum_file -ItemType File }

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Add-Content -Path $sum_file -Value (Get-Content $file.FullName) -Encoding Ascii
    if (-not (Test-Path "$($arch_dir)/$($file.Name)")) {
        Move-item $file.FullName $arch_dir
    } else {
        $i = 0
        $nfn = ''

        do {
            $nfn = "$($file.BaseName)-$($i.ToString()).txt"
            $i++
        } while (Test-Path -Path "$($arch_dir)/$($nfn)")

        Move-Item $file.FullName "$($arch_dir)/$($nfn)"
    }
}
```

Run this script from a cmd.exe shell or .bat file using:

```
powershell -noprofile -file .\esomover.ps1
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a Windows Batch file to me.

Comment: @3D1T0R; Added direction to use this in a cmd.exe shell or .bat file.

Comment: @3D1T0R; The OP does not have to do anything. If this does not work for their purpose, they can just not use it. PowerShell can be installed on XP.

Comment: It is for Windows server 2016. I am not as familiar with Powershell but if this works than I may be able to utilize it.

Comment: Maybe I'm a little confused by the powershell. I already have a .bat to write the ESOInput.txt I only want the previously processed text files in the root to be moved to \ESOMoved\ directiory.

Comment: This script also appends to the ESOInput.txt file using ADD-content. If these are done separately, there could be a new file come in that does not get appended but does get moved.